# How do I detect a payment canceled by a user in an in-app payment?

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I implemented in-app payment properly using react-native-iap(version: 12.10.5).

However, I don't know what to do about payments canceled by users.

I think stores are so unfriendly...

Anyway like the title, How do I detect a payment canceled by a user?

I tried to call getPurchaseHistory(). I expected I could know purchaseStatus. But, there is no status value.